# Коллайдер объекта перекрывает коллайдер другого объекта. Unity

Tags: unity3d

Есть два объекта, допустим синий квадрат 2x2 с коллайдером и висящий на нём скрипт с OnMouseDown. Также есть красный квадрат с коллайдером, расположенный в том же месте, но размером 1x1, и также висящий на нём другой скрипт с OnMouseDown. Красный квадрат видно над синим, но при нажатии на эти квадраты выполняется всегда OnMouseDown синего, большого квадрата. Оба квадрат IsTrigger. Оба статичны. Как сделать так чтобы выполнялся OnMouseDown красного квадрата при нажатии в его область 1x1, а на остальной области, которая синия, выполнялся OnMouseDown синего квадрата? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Можете воспользоваться raycast`ом - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SnyL6OLdcMg

Comment: Спасибо Большое!!!

Comment: Можете попробовать внести изменения в иерархию сцены. Но я не уверен что это может помочь.

Comment: Обошёлся изменением координаты Z у коллайдера. Я просто не понял сначала, что координата должна быть с минусом, а не с плюсом, чтобы быть выше над другим коллайдером.